# Is this code for a search query faulty? Trying to debug someone else's website

Tags: php

I'm trying to help a friend with her website, and a few search boxes on the site don't seem to be retrieving any results.  Is there anything in this section of code which might be faulty, specifically within those queries?

```
if ($_SESSION['searchvars']['res']) {

    $query = '';

    $restable    = 'clrcr_rets_property';
    $fieldstoget = "ModificationTimestamp,PropertyType,BedroomsTotal,BathsTotal,SqftMain,ListingId,StandardStatus,ListPrice,City,StreetDirPrefix,StreetNumber,StreetName,ListOfficeName,ListOfficeMlsId,imageref";

    $query .= "SELECT $fieldstoget FROM `$restable` WHERE PropertyType = 'Residential'";

    $query .= (isset($_SESSION['searchvars']['maxprice']))   ? " WHERE ListPrice <= '{$_SESSION['searchvars']['maxprice']}'" : '';
    $query .= (isset($_SESSION['searchvars']['minsqft']))    ? " WHERE SqftMain >= '{$_SESSION['searchvars']['minsqft']}'" : '';
    $query .= (isset($_SESSION['searchvars']['schooldist'])) ? " WHERE SchoolDistrict LIKE '%{$_SESSION['searchvars']['schooldist']}%'" : '';
    $query .= (isset($_SESSION['searchvars']['foundation'])) ? " WHERE FoundationType LIKE '%{$_SESSION['searchvars']['foundation']}%'" : '';

    $slug   = 'residential';
    $type   = 'residential properties';

}
```

The results just seem to keep giving me nothing, when I know it should be finding things.  Has the syntax changed since this code was initially written?

Comment: Print out what the query actually ends up as. `Where` the problem is should be clear.

Comment: Doh, I had added the first WHERE on my own to fix a change in the database and it hadn't dawned on me that the WHEREs in the next line were compounding.  Thanks, Tim.